# C++ wrapper around uniform mt19937 SequenceContainer

Tags: c++, random, template, wrapper

With the following interface in mind

```
EasyRandom<unsigned int> prng(a, b);
auto x = prng();   // scalar
auto v = prng(10); // vector
```

I wrote the following class:

```
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution
template <typename T = unsigned int>
class EasyRandom
{
private:
  std::random_device rd;
  std::unique_ptr<std::mt19937> gen;
  std::unique_ptr<std::uniform_int_distribution<T>> dist;

public:
  EasyRandom(T a, T b)
  {
    gen = std::make_unique<std::mt19937>(rd());
    dist = std::make_unique<std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>(a, b);
  }

  T operator()() { return (*dist)(*gen); }

  std::vector<T> operator()(size_t n)
  {
    std::vector<T> v;
    for (; n > 0; v.push_back(operator()()), --n);
    return v;
  }
};
```

I also have a few specific questions:

1. Is there a way to instantiate `EasyRandom` without the use of pointers?
2. Is it possible to change `operator()(size_t n)` to return any user-specified [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) (e.g. vector, list, deque) instead of hard-coding it to a particular implementation (e.g. `std::vector`)?

Comment: As **@1201ProgramAlarm** already pointed out the second part of your question is off-topic and could lead to your entire question being closed. Please revise your question if you want to prevent this.

Comment: Adding a non-working implementation does not make the question on topic for Code Review. We require the code be working. For more information, see the [help/on-topic]. I have rolled back the edit you made to avoid incurring closevotes.

Comment: Some notes on what you've got so far: 1. Keeping the instance of `std::random_device` that you use only once wastes space. 2. Instantiating one `std::unique_ptr<std::mt19937>` per distribution wastes **a lot** of space and makes creating distributions really slow. You typically want exactly one generator per thread that is generating random numbers, so make the generator `[static] thread_local`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gen` and `dist` don't need to be pointers.  Just declare them as members, and use the member initializer list in the constructor to initialize them.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen;
std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist;

EasyRandom(T a, T b): gen(rd()), dist(a, b) {
}
```

In the `operator()` that returns a vector, you can reserve space for the vector to avoid memory reallocations during the insertions (`v.reserve(n)`).  While not an issue with ints, if you use `emplace_back` rather than `push_back` that can avoid potential extra copies of a value for non-simple types.

The second question is off topic (code not implemented).

Comment: Added implementation for second question. Thank you for your feedback so far.